# How to merge code coverage from two different sonar projects

Tags: github, version-control, sonarqube, code-coverage

I have two sonar projects, one is getting UT coverage and other one is capturing FT coverage. Since these are two different sonar project thats why I can not bind both to my single git repo.

Is there any way by which I can merge these two projects report and integrate that with my PR decoration check?

Sonar version 9.9.1